# How to get /dev/tpm* in initramfs?

Tags: initramfs, tpm

For passwordless decryption of a LUKS volume I want to use clevis with my TPM 2.0 module. This module is recognised in Debian Testing (bullseye): `/dev/tpm0` and `/dev/tpmrm0` exist (so that I am able to run the necessary clevis commands in Debian).

However, the clevis initramfs scripts fail. Having investigated this in an `init=premount` shell, I discovered that in initramfs the `/dev/tpm*` devices mentioned above **do not exist**. How can I change this? Using Debian, I generate my initramfs with `initramfs-tools`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the kernel modules that drive the TPM get loaded within initramfs by listing them in `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`. Then the initramfs `udev` should create the devices for you.

First, run `lsmod | grep tpm` to find your TPM driver module(s). For me, the output looks like this:

```
# lsmod |grep tpm
tpm_tis                16384  0
tpm_tis_core           20480  1 tpm_tis
tpm                    61440  2 tpm_tis,tpm_tis_core
rng_core               16384  2 tpm
```

`tpm_tis` is the driver for the most common TPM implementations on x86 hardware. From the output, we can see that it depends on other modules: `tpm_tis_core`, `tpm`and `rng_core`. The `lsmod` list is built up from bottom up, so the optimal loading order would be to load the `rng_core` first.

So, to make sure these modules get loaded in initramfs, you would add four lines to the `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` file:

```
rng_core
tpm
tpm_tis_core
tpm_tis
```

(This is probably overkill. I think `initramfs-tools` can now handle module dependencies automatically, so just mentioning `tpm_tis` alone would probably be enough. But I like to specify the modules explicitly to minimize the need to retry things...)

Once you've edited the `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` file, you'll need to recreate your initramfs file. In Debian, that's easiest done with `update-initramfs -u`.

The next step would be to reboot and use the `init=premount` shell again to confirm that the `/dev/tpm*` devices now get created for you.